# Custom TableViewCell are shown white and empty in my TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have created a custom TableViewCell class named OptionsTableViewCell and a custom TableViewController class named WPOptionsTableViewController. The cells are always empty and white. Here is what I've done so far :

AppDelegate.m :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

     self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] ];
     WPOptionsViewController *vc = [[WPOptionsViewController alloc] init]
     UITableView *view = vc.tableView;
     [view registerClass:[OptionsTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"OptionsTableViewCell"];

     self.window.rootViewController = vc;
     [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
     return YES;
}
```

OptionsTableViewCell.m :

```
- (instancetype) initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if ( self )
    {
        self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        self.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
     [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
     [self highlight:selected];
}

- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated {
     [super setHighlighted:highlighted animated:animated];
     [self highlight:highlighted];

}

- (void)highlight:(BOOL) highlight {
     UIColor *tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
     if ( highlight ) 
          tintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.6];

     self.textLabel.textColor = tintColor;
}
```

WPOptionsTableViewController.m :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];

     self.tableView.delegate = self;
     self.tableView.dataSource = self;
     self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
     self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(80, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
     self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

// Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 3;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     OptionsTableViewCell *cell = [[OptionsTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"OptionsTableViewCell"];
     if ( indexPath.row == 0 )
         cell.textLabel.text = @"Home";
     if ( indexPath.row == 1 )
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Profile";
     if ( indexPath.row == 2 )
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Settings";
     return cell;
}
```

No need to use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier as I have only 3 rows

EDIT: I don't use any XIB file. The problem seems to be in my custom cell implementation but I can't see anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is because, you're setting textColor to white in your highlight method of OptionTableViewCell. By default,as its not being highlighted, the BOOL value of highlight will be NO. Give an else condition and replace the tint color with black color. You can see the text.

```
UIColor *tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Comment: Yes, this is where the problem was. The text color has always been white or a "softer" white, never yellow.